# R Data Frame filter by Category ID for multiple logical conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I'm trying to filter a data frame which uses a column index (called Insider CIK).  I'd like to use a logical test to exclude CIK Numbers that don't have both a P-Purchase and S-Sale or an M-Exempt in the table.  Each line is a separate transaction identified by a corresponding CIK number and some can be P-Purchases or S-Sales so if for a given CIK number if they're transaction logs are exclusively one type I'd like to drop them.  I've tried the dplyr filter function but the way I'm doing it it only considers each line and whether it meets the condition rather than the group (CIK Number) as a whole.

Here is my sample script and a dput:

```
test8 <- test7 %>% group_by(`Insider CIK`) %>% filter(`Transaction Type`=='P-Purchase' & `Transaction Type`=='S-Sale' | `Transaction Type`=='M-Exempt')

dput(head(test7[c('Insider CIK', 'Transaction Type')], 100))
structure(list(`Insider CIK` = c("0001027035", "0001027035", 
"0001027035", "0001027035", "0001027035", "0001027035", "0001032553", 
"0001032553", "0001032553", "0001032553", "0001032553", "0001032553", 
"0001032553", "0001032553", "0001032553", "0001032553", "0001032553", 
"0001032553", "0001032553", "0001032553", "0001032553", "0001032553", 
"0001032553", "0001032553", "0001032553", "0001032553", "0001032553", 
"0001032553", "0001032553", "0001032553", "0001032553", "0001032553", 
"0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", 
"0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", 
"0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", 
"0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", 
"0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", 
"0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", 
"0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", 
"0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", 
"0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", 
"0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", 
"0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", 
"0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", 
"0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331", 
"0001033331", "0001033331", "0001033331"), `Transaction Type` = c("S-Sale", 
"S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", 
"S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", 
"S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", 
"S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", 
"S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", 
"S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "M-Exempt", "S-Sale", 
"S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "M-Exempt", 
"S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", 
"S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "M-Exempt", 
"S-Sale", "M-Exempt", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", 
"S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "M-Exempt", "S-Sale", 
"M-Exempt", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "M-Exempt", "S-Sale", 
"S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "M-Exempt", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", 
"M-Exempt", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", 
"M-Exempt", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale", 
"S-Sale", "S-Sale", "S-Sale")), row.names = 2:101, class = "data.frame")
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: You have not provided test7 so your code does not allow us to reproduce your problem

Comment: Do you need `test7 %>% 
  group_by(\`Insider CIK\`) %>% 
  filter(any(\`Transaction Type\`=='P-Purchase') & (any(\`Transaction Type\`=='S-Sale' | \`Transaction Type\`=='M-Exempt')))
` ?

Comment: The subset you have provided only has single Transaction Type values. Consider providing a larger sample of your data.

Comment: You got it with adding "any."  Thank you very much for the very helpful suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can check the condition and use `any` to get the entire group :

```
library(dplyr)

test7 %>% 
  group_by(`Insider CIK`) %>% 
  filter(any(`Transaction Type`=='P-Purchase') & 
        (any(`Transaction Type`=='S-Sale' | `Transaction Type`=='M-Exempt')))
```

Comment: That's a hugely helpful approach for checking categories.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test7)[, .SD[any(`Transaction Type`=='P-Purchase') & 
    (any(`Transaction Type`=='S-Sale' | `Transaction Type`=='M-Exempt')],  by = `Insider CIK`]
```